# Java Error javax/swing/text/GlyphView.getBreakSpot Found on running a command

Tags: java, linux, jvm

I was trying to run a software dbvis on linux and found the following error about java

```
CompilerOracle: exclude javax/swing/text/GlyphView.getBreakSpot
```

Any solution.

Comment: please add some code.

Comment: Its a command line ubuntu command to run the software dbvisullizer i did'nt code anything just trying to launch DBvis

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error. This is an informational message from JVM telling that just-in-time compilation of the given method is explicitly disabled by the command-line options.

The purpose of this option is to work-around the bug in earlier versions of JVM that resulted in a crash caused  by incorrectly compiled method `GlyphView.getBreakSpot`, see [JDK-8060036](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8060036).